# w3wp.exe keeping files locked after processing in webservice

Tags: .net, web-services, w3wp

I have a webservice and I noted that some dlls in the wwwroot folder are kept logged after the webservice is executed.

After restart of pc, the problem is solved.

Can i have something in my code that releases the dlls?

Comment: Is this a WCF service, or a legacy ASMX service?

Comment: Hi John, this is a normal webservice

Answer (score 12):

Try to either recycle the AppPool which your webservices runs under, or use iisreset.

`iisreset /stop` will stop IIS and release the dll's. `iisreset /start` will start IIS back up again.

If you recycle the Application Pool, then the lock of dll's will be released until someone hits your webservice again, and aquires a new lock.

Comment: @mouthpiec - you can maybe restart the *app pool* from your C# code if you use ADSI and your code is not running under the same app pool. But don't try restarting the IIS instance from your code, especially if your code is running in that IIS version (your code will effectively be shutting itself down). An iisreset is an administrative type task, and should always be done manually, you may have to plan ahead if you need to do it and others are using the server.

Comment: @mouthpiec - Can you describe your scenario for why you want to unlock the dll's? Then it's easier to advise on the route to go.

Comment: This does not work. The site and web server are both stopped, and the file is still locked by w3wp according to process explorer. Windows 10. Still completely broken. Amazing that these file locking issues have been around since XP and still not resolved.